# Split a long table into two pages

Tags: tables

HI I have created a table from R and the table looks like this but it extends more than a page and the rest of table beyond the page region is hidden.

Can anyone suggest what can I do here ?

The table looks like this:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrr}
  \hline
 & a & t = 0.1 & t = 1 & t = 5 & t = 10 \\ 
  \hline
1 & -10.00 &  & 0.99 & 4.74 & 8.52 \\ 
   \hline
2 & -9.50 &  & 0.99 & 4.71 & 8.34 \\ 
   \hline
3 & -9.00 &  & 0.99 & 4.68 & 8.14 \\ 
   \hline
4 & -8.50 &  & 0.99 & 4.64 & 7.90 \\ 
   \hline
5 & -8.00 & 0.10 & 0.98 & 4.59 & 7.64 \\ 
   \hline
6 & -7.50 & 0.10 & 0.98 & 4.54 & 7.34 \\ 
   \hline
7 & -7.00 & 0.10 & 0.98 & 4.47 & 7.01 \\ 
   \hline
8 & -6.50 & 0.10 & 0.98 & 4.39 & 6.65 \\ 
   \hline
9 & -6.00 & 0.10 & 0.97 & 4.29 & 6.26 \\ 
   \hline
10 & -5.50 & 0.10 & 0.97 & 4.17 & 5.84 \\ 
   \hline
11 & -5.00 & 0.10 & 0.96 & 4.03 & 5.40 \\ 
   \hline
12 & -4.50 & 0.10 & 0.96 & 3.85 & 4.94 \\ 
   \hline
13 & -4.00 & 0.10 & 0.95 & 3.64 & 4.46 \\ 
   \hline
14 & -3.50 & 0.10 & 0.93 & 3.38 & 3.98 \\ 
   \hline
15 & -3.00 & 0.10 & 0.91 & 3.08 & 3.49 \\ 
   \hline
16 & -2.50 & 0.10 & 0.88 & 2.73 & 2.99 \\ 
   \hline
17 & -2.00 & 0.10 & 0.84 & 2.34 & 2.50 \\ 
   \hline
18 & -1.50 & 0.10 & 0.78 & 1.91 & 2.00 \\ 
   \hline
19 & -1.00 & 0.09 & 0.67 & 1.46 & 1.50 \\ 
   \hline
20 & -0.50 & 0.08 & 0.51 & 0.98 & 1.00 \\ 
   \hline
21 & 0.00 & 0.03 & 0.25 & 0.49 & 0.50 \\ 
   \hline
22 & 0.50 & 0.08 & 0.51 & 0.98 & 1.00 \\ 
   \hline
23 & 1.00 & 0.09 & 0.67 & 1.46 & 1.50 \\ 
   \hline
24 & 1.50 & 0.10 & 0.78 & 1.91 & 2.00 \\ 
   \hline
25 & 2.00 & 0.10 & 0.84 & 2.34 & 2.50 \\ 
   \hline
26 & 2.50 & 0.10 & 0.88 & 2.73 & 2.99 \\ 
   \hline
27 & 3.00 & 0.10 & 0.91 & 3.08 & 3.49 \\ 
   \hline
28 & 3.50 & 0.10 & 0.93 & 3.38 & 3.98 \\ 
   \hline
29 & 4.00 & 0.10 & 0.95 & 3.64 & 4.46 \\ 
   \hline
30 & 4.50 & 0.10 & 0.96 & 3.85 & 4.94 \\ 
   \hline
31 & 5.00 & 0.10 & 0.96 & 4.03 & 5.40 \\ 
   \hline
32 & 5.50 & 0.10 & 0.97 & 4.17 & 5.84 \\ 
   \hline
33 & 6.00 & 0.10 & 0.97 & 4.29 & 6.26 \\ 
   \hline
34 & 6.50 & 0.10 & 0.98 & 4.39 & 6.65 \\ 
   \hline
35 & 7.00 & 0.10 & 0.98 & 4.47 & 7.01 \\ 
   \hline
36 & 7.50 & 0.10 & 0.98 & 4.54 & 7.34 \\ 
   \hline
37 & 8.00 & 0.10 & 0.98 & 4.59 & 7.64 \\ 
   \hline
38 & 8.50 & 0.10 & 0.99 & 4.64 & 7.90 \\ 
   \hline
39 & 9.00 &  & 0.99 & 4.68 & 8.14 \\ 
   \hline
40 & 9.50 &  & 0.99 & 4.71 & 8.34 \\ 
   \hline
41 & 10.00 &  & 0.99 & 4.74 & 8.52 \\ 
   \hline
42 & 10.50 &  & 0.99 & 4.76 & 8.68 \\ 
   \hline
43 & 11.00 &  & 0.99 & 4.78 & 8.81 \\ 
   \hline
44 & 11.50 &  & 0.99 & 4.80 & 8.93 \\ 
   \hline
45 & 12.00 &  & 0.99 & 4.82 & 9.03 \\ 
   \hline
46 & 12.50 &  & 0.99 & 4.83 & 9.12 \\ 
   \hline
47 & 13.00 &  & 0.99 & 4.85 & 9.20 \\ 
   \hline
48 & 13.50 &  & 0.99 & 4.86 & 9.27 \\ 
   \hline
49 & 14.00 &  & 0.99 & 4.87 & 9.33 \\ 
   \hline
50 & 14.50 &  & 1.00 & 4.88 & 9.38 \\ 
   \hline
51 & 15.00 &  & 1.00 & 4.89 & 9.43 \\ 
   \hline
52 & 15.50 &  & 1.00 & 4.89 & 9.47 \\ 
   \hline
53 & 16.00 &  & 1.00 & 4.90 & 9.51 \\ 
   \hline
54 & 16.50 &  & 1.00 & 4.91 & 9.55 \\ 
   \hline
55 & 17.00 &  & 1.00 & 4.91 & 9.58 \\ 
   \hline
56 & 17.50 &  & 1.00 & 4.92 & 9.61 \\ 
   \hline
57 & 18.00 &  & 1.00 & 4.92 & 9.63 \\ 
   \hline
58 & 18.50 &  & 1.00 & 4.93 & 9.65 \\ 
   \hline
59 & 19.00 &  & 1.00 & 4.93 & 9.67 \\ 
   \hline
60 & 19.50 &  & 1.00 & 4.93 & 9.69 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{summary statistics of air pollution data} 
\end{table}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: The `longtable` package can split a table across pages.

Comment: I guess you are looking for `longtable`. You can [read the documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) or [search the `longtable` questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/longtable).

Comment: I know longtable can be used but I couldn't fix it in this example. Where exactly do I need to insert longtable ? Do I replace tabular with longtable ?

Comment: @Jdbaba In your example, _there is no `longtable`_. Please, edit your question and ask a specific question that addresses your precise issues. And please, make it into a full [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @tohecz Problem Fixed. I will try to provide full minimal working example next time. Thanks.